# error 13 in Inputbox/ Switch case statement

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to a macro to get top 3 street addresses from a keyword and let the user choose one. However, I kept running into error 13( mismatched data type) on my "case 1" statement or in the last input box. Any help?I am relatively new to VBA.

```
Sub myTest2()

    Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
    Dim domDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim query As String
    Dim myNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim myNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim nNode As Integer
    Dim re As Range
    Dim result(2) As String


    'allows user to select range
    Set myValue = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the list of addresses wether empty or not of the organizations", Type:=8)
    Set myValueCol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the column with the names", Type:=8)

    For Each re In myValue
        If IsEmpty(re.Value) Or re.Value = vbNullString Then
            query = Cells(re.Row, myValueCol.Column)
            query = Replace(query, " ", "+")
            query = Replace(query, ",", "%2C")

            'You must acquire a google api key and enter it here
            Dim googleKey As String
            googleKey = "KEY_HERE" 'your api key here

            'Send a "GET" request for place/textsearch
            Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
            xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" & query & "&key=" & googleKey, False
            xhrRequest.send

            'Save the response into a document
            Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
            domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

            Set myNodes = domDoc.SelectNodes("//result/formatted_address")

            For nNode = 0 To 2

                Set myNode = myNodes(nNode)
                If Not (myNode Is Nothing) Then
                    result(nNode) = myNode.Text
                End If
                If myNode Is Nothing Then
                    result(nNode) = "no additional adresses found"
                End If
            Next nNode
            sinput = Application.InputBox(prompt:="1. " & result(0) & vbNewLine & "2. " & result(1) & vbNewLine & "3. " & result(2), Type:=1)

            Select Case sinput
             Case 1
                re = result0
             Case 2
                re = result1
             Case 3
                re = result2
             End Select

        End If
    Next re

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `result0` declared? Do you mean `result(0)`, which will still be a mismatch because you'd be trying to assign a String to a Range?

Comment: Shouldn't those case lines read `result(0)` not `result0` ?

Comment: You should define `result` like this `Dim result(0 To 2) As String`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me. Thank you :)

Sub allowUserToChooseLocation()

```
Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim domDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim query As String
Dim myNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim myNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim nNode As Integer
Dim re As Range
Dim result(0 To 2) As String


'allows user to select range
Set myValue = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the list of addresses wether empty or not of the organizations", Type:=8)
Set myValueCol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the column with the names", Type:=8)

For Each re In myValue
        If IsEmpty(re.Value) Or re.Value = vbNullString Then
        query = Cells(re.Row, myValueCol.Column)
       query = Replace(query, " ", "+")
       query = Replace(query, ",", "%2C")

'You must acquire a google api key and enter it here
Dim googleKey As String
googleKey = "Key_Here" 'your api key here

'Send a "GET" request for place/textsearch
Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
```

xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" & query & "&key=AIzaSyAmkY6nbeMGS19t0jdcFQT_SxoFcm7LUdE", False
    xhrRequest.send

```
'Save the response into a document
Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

Set myNodes = domDoc.SelectNodes("//result/formatted_address")

    For nNode = 0 To 2

    Set myNode = myNodes(nNode)

    If Not (myNode Is Nothing) Then
    result(nNode) = myNode.nodeTypedValue
    End If

    If (myNode Is Nothing) Then
    result(nNode) = "No additonal addresses found"
    End If


    Next nNode
    sinput = Application.InputBox(prompt:="1. " & result(0) & vbNewLine & "2. " & result(1) & vbNewLine & "3. " & result(2), Type:=1)

    Select Case sinput
     Case 1
        re.Value = result(0)
     Case 2
        re.Value = result(1)
     Case 3
        re.Value = result(2)
     End Select
```

End If
        Next re

End Sub